# statistics - calculate p-value

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

From the daily production of a given fertilizer, six small portions were collected and analyzed to calculate the percentage of nitrogen.

The results observed were as follows:
6.2 5.7 5.8 5.8 6.0 5.9

It is known from experience that the analysis process provides values with a distribution that can be considered Normal.
Do the observations support the assurance that the expected percentage of nitrogen, µ, differs from 6% at a 10% significance level? Answer the question by calculating p - value

I calculate:

s^2 = 0.032

t = (5.9-6)/(sqrt(0.032 /sqrt(6))) = -1.369

and p value = 2P(Z<-1.369) = 2(1-0.9147)= 0.1706

but the correct value of p value is
 p-value = 0.229204974, 0.2 ≤ p − value ≤ 0.3

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypothesis is $$H_0 : \mu = \mu_0 = 6, \quad \text{vs.} \quad H_a : \mu \ne 6,$$ where $\mu$ is the true mean percentage of nitrogen.  The test statistic is $$T \mid H_0 = \frac{\bar x - \mu_0}{s/\sqrt{n}} \sim \color{red}{\operatorname{StudentT}(df = n-1)},$$ where $\bar x$ is the sample mean, $\mu_0$ is the hypothesized mean under $H_0$, $s$ is the sample standard deviation, and $n = 6$ is the sample size.  You will note that because $s$ is not the true standard deviation, as it is unknown, and you are using the sample itself to estimate the standard deviation, $T \mid H_0$ is not normally distributed:  it is student $t$-distributed with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.  Therefore, while your calculation of the test statistic is correct, your calculation of the $p$-value is not because you are using the wrong null distribution.  To fix this, you would either look up the value of the test statistic $-1.369$ in a $t$-table, or you can use a calculator or computer.  You will get $$\Pr[T \le -1.36931 \mid H_0] \approx 0.114602,$$ which gives you the one-tailed test $p$-value.  The two-tailed test has a $p$-value twice as large, namely $$\Pr[|T| \ge -1.36931 \mid H_0] = 2\Pr[T \le -1.36931 \mid H_0] \approx 0.229205.$$

You can perform the computation in [WolframAlpha with the command](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%20CDF%5BStudentTDistribution%5B5%5D%2C%20-1.36930639%5D)

```
2 CDF[StudentTDistribution[5], -1.36930639]
```

Comment: What role does it play the definition of the alternative hypothesis in this context? It is not used to compute the p-value...

Comment: @Thomas That is not correct.  $H_a$ tells us that the test is two-sided, hence the rejection region is of the form $|T| > c$ for some constant $c$ that is a function of the significance level $\alpha$.  The $p$-value must also be computed for a two-sided test.

Comment: What you mean is that if you had taken as alternative $\mu >6$ than you would have taken only a one-sided test right? What is the derivation of this? At the end of the day values smaller than 6 can be obtained even if the mean is larger than 6. I always imagined that the condition for making one or two sided tests is a modification of H0 (which is the only quantity that you condition on in the equations you write), where the densitiy of H0 is multiplied by the corresponding indicator function. I find often this doubt and that is why I took the occasion to ask...

Comment: Or maybe one can derive the test maximizing in some sense the power with respect to some alternative?